# Need to extract strings from main string using PHP

Tags: php, html, extract

My main string look like this

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 1
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 2
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 3
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 4
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 5
</div>
```

here i want to extract the string in between the tags `<div class="large-12 columns">` and `</div>`

I already have function to extract the content in between two strings, but its getting only the first tags (text 1)

In the above main string i have given 5 texts, but the real string may contain 1 to 30.

Anybody done this before, since i am new to PHP.

My code which i use to extract the string.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
$string = " ".$string;
 $ini = strpos($string,$start);
 if ($ini == 0) return "";
 $ini += strlen($start);     
 $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
 return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
```

Comment: add the code you already have.

Comment: http://au1.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: share how did you try...(php script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:**edited**

```
 <?php
$str='<div class="large-12 columns">
text 1
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 2
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 3
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 4
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 5
</div>';
$str1=str_replace('<div class="large-12 columns">','',$str);
$arr=str_replace('</div>',',',$str1);
$arr1=explode(',',$arr);
$values=array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($value) && $value!=''){
    $values[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($values);
```

Comment: This leaves </divs> in the array and starts at index 1. Modifying to provide cleaner array for use in php.

Comment: @nwolybugis print_r returning </div> to you.

Comment: Result in view source: 'Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
text 1
</div>

    [2] => 
text 2
</div>

    [3] => 
text 3
</div>

    [4] => 
text 4
</div>

    [5] => 
text 5
</div>
)'

Comment: Why first replace and then explode? Why not just `explode('</div>', $str);`? And add an `array_shift` after the explode so the first element won't be `null`.

Comment: I tried a few things (strip_tags, str_replace) and this set up worked best for me with clean code. explode on </div> would still leave the opening div tag with class info in the array. The OP just wants the text between the div tags. Unfortunately, they don't state how they want to handle the data afterwards, so putting in an array or variable separated by commas is left to us.

Comment: Tried the code, and the code works for clear strings. But the real string have a lot of tags and i am getting the main string from this url http://www.anandabazar.com/state using file_get_contents()

Comment: if this is the case and if you already know the tags you can do like this:foreach($tag as $onetag){// where $tag is array of all like <div class="large-12 columns">
 $str1=str_replace('$onetag','',$str);
}

Answer (score 0):

The PHP version...

```
<?php 
$str='<div class="large-12 columns">
text 1
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 2
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 3
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 4
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 5
</div>';
$arr2 = str_replace('</div>', ',', $str);
$arr = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($arr as &$value){
    $value = strip_tags($value);
}
print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

jQuery does this easily. The .text() function pulls the information stored in the divs with class ".large-12" and puts them in a variable called info. Since I didn't know what you were going to do with them, I used the same .text() function to place them in a div further down with id extracted_divs
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwolybug/oxodkbwL/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var info = $(".large-12").text();
    $("#extracted_divs").text(info);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="large-12 columns">
text 1
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 2
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 3
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 4
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
text 5
</div>

<div id="extracted_divs">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is tagged `php`, not `jquery`.